# Appending tuple to an empty list

Tags: list, python-3.x, tuples

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
website_path = GetValidDirectory("Enter the path to the website : ")

websitelink_list = []   #List of tuples containing the source link information
print(websitelink_list)
htmlfiles = []          #List of the html files we analyze on the site

for dirname, subdir_list, file_list in os.walk(website_path):

    for file in file_list:

        #Check the file extension.  Only analyze files that are .html
        filename, fileext = os.path.splitext(file)
        if fileext == ".html":
            relative_file = MakeFullPath(dirname, file)

            full_file = os.path.realpath(relative_file)

            htmlfiles.append( (full_file, relative_file) )

            filelinks = FileLinkTuples(dirname, file)
            print(filelinks)
            websitelink_list.extend(filelinks)


#Files that do not have a link to them.
```

functions:

```
def GetValidDirectory(prompt : str) -> str:
""" Returns a valid directory entered from the user.

     Arguments :
          prompt : str - The text displayed to the user asking them to enter a directory.
     Returns : String of a valid directory that the user entered.
     Errors  : Displays a warning if the user does not enter a valid directory.
"""

while True:
    try:
        str_prompt = input(prompt)
        prompt_dir = os.path.realpath(str_prompt)
        ch_dir = os.chdir(str_prompt)
    except IOError:
        print("Please enter a valid directory")
        continue
    return prompt_dir

def MakeFullPath(path : str, filename : str) -> str:
""" combines path and filename for a full filename.  If path does not end in \\ then it appends it

     Arguments : 
          path : str, the path to the file
          filename : str, the name of the file.
     Returns : 
          path concatenated with filename.  
             If path does not end with a backslash, then append one if path has data in it.

"""
no_data = []
if os.listdir(path) != no_data:
   relative_file = os.path.join(path,filename)
return relative_file


def FileLinkTuples(path : str, filename : str) -> list:
"""Returns a tuple of links from the file 
     Arguments :
          path : str - The path to the filename.  Might be relative path.
          filename : str - The name of the html file to open and analyze.
     Returns : list of tuples.  
          Each tuple has the 4 values. 
               HTMLFile - HTML file and path to the source file the link was found in.
               fulllinkpath - Full path to the link on the system.  Not a relative path.
               linkpath - Path and name to the link specified.  Relative address. 
               file exists - Boolean indicating if the file at the full link path exists.
           Example 
                [ (('sample\\index.html', 'C:\\Website Analysis\\downloads.html', 'downloads.html', True)
                ]

"""

filelink_list = []
a = path.split('\\')
b = os.path.join(a[-1],filename)
c = os.path.realpath(filename)
if os.path.isfile(filename) == "True":
    filelink_list.append((b,c,filename,"True"))
return filelink_list
```

Can someone please analyze my codes and tell me why the typles of (full_file,relative_file) and filelinks are not appending to the empty lists in the main program?

For this assignment, i was given a Unittest.  The functions passed the test, but i don't know why the lists in the main program are not updating?

When i print the websitelink_list and htmlfiles, they are both empty.

What am i doing wrong with the def FileLinkTuples? particularly the

```
if os.path.isfile(filename) == "True":
    filelink_list.append((b,c,filename,"True"))
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the inner parts of the loop are actually being executed?

Comment: yes, i used print statements to verify that@Rufflewind

Comment: So what happens if you try to print, say, `(full_file, relative_file)` just before it's appended?  I can't think of any reason why the append would fail if the inner loops are being properly executed, regardless of what your other functions do.

Comment: @Rufflewind, both paths were printed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your code does produce nonempty results for `htmlfiles` at least.  The main problem that I see is this:

```
if os.path.isfile(filename) == "True":
```

The function returns a Boolean, not a string, so you should check against the Boolean value `True`, or even omit it altogether:

```
if os.path.isfile(filename):
```

After fixing that, you should expect something in `websitelink_list` as well, provided your directory does in fact contain `*.html` files.

Now, if you are not seeing anything in `htmlfiles` at all (even if the directory does contain `*.html` files) then it must be something else that you're not showing here, since it appears to work correctly on my computer.